# How can I select an element with multiple classes in BeautifulSoup4 - Python?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Here we have a small piece of a html page:

```
1 st scenario:
<p class="food_price">
  <span class="food_price on_sale">$45</span>
  <span class="food_price">$65</span>
</p>

2 nd scenario
<p class="food_price">
  <span class="price">$35</span>
</p>
```

When the class `on_sale` is available I want to set the variable price_sale = the value inside the span. When it is not I want to set the variable value to -1.

This teh code I am using:

```
price_sale     = product_item.find('span',class_='food_price on_sale')
price_price    = product_item.find('span',class_='food_price').text

print(price_sale) #when there is no 'food_price on_sale' display None

if price_sale=='None':
    price_sale = -1
else:
    price_sale = product_item.find('span',class_='price sale').text

print(price_sale)
```

I am getting the follow error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ila/vhosts/crawler/bucky.py", line 144, in <module>
    price_sale = product_item.find('span',class_='food_price on_sale').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

It seems that when there is no `class="food_price on_sale"` it is not going into `if price_sale=='None':`. My guess is taht it seems that `None` is not a string.

Does someone knows how to compare this?

Answer (score 1):

This should help.

**Demo:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
s = """<p class="food_price">
  <span class="food_price on_sale">$45</span>
  <span class="food_price">$65</span>
</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")
price_sale = soup.find('span',class_='food_price on_sale')

if price_sale:
    price_sale = price_sale.text
else:
    price_sale = -1
print(price_sale)
```

**Output:**

```
$45
```